# MongoDB - adding subdocument in an array

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, list

How can I perform this in python? adding subdocument in an array

```
Name: xxx 
Age: xxx 
Subject : 
          Chemistry 90
          Math 100

**into** 

Name: xxx 
Age: xxx 
Subject : 
          Chemistry 90
          Math 100
          History 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you are using a module such as pymongo you can do the following. I'm sure there are multiple ways to do this.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
mongoConn=MongoClient("mongodb://"+username+":"+password+"@<instancename>:27017")
db="<dbName>"
collection="<collection name>"
query={"Name":"XXX"}
result=mongoConn[db][collection].find_one(query)
print(result)
```

Then using $set you can update the value.

```
result['Subject']['history']=80
updates={ "$set": result['Subject']}
mongoConn[db][collection].update_one(query,updates)
result=mongoConn[db][collection].find_one(query)
print(result)
```

This should update `{"Name": "XXX", "Age": 10, "Class": "ABC",  "Course":{"Chemistry":100,"Math":90}}`

To`{"Name": "XXX", "Age": 10, "Class": "ABC",  "Course":{"Chemistry":100,"Math":90,'history':80}}`

The above is not the most efficient way of doing this as you are writing the subdocument again to the db, but you can use $addToSet as mentioned in below answer to make a more specific change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet)

```py
temp.find_one({'name':{'$eq': 'james'}})
```

output

```json
{'_id': ObjectId('5ffbdd9250b6bede0aae3d7d'),
 'name': 'james',
 'age': 100,
 'subject': [{'chemistry': 90}, {'math': 100}]}
```

you can use

```py
r = temp.update_one({'name': 'james'}, {'$addToSet': {'subject': {'history': 80}}})
```

output

```json
{'_id': ObjectId('5ffbdd9250b6bede0aae3d7d'),
 'name': 'james',
 'age': 100,
 'subject': [{'chemistry': 90}, {'math': 100}, {'history': 90}]}
```

Comment: How to show to output, Sorry I'm new to this database. I used this way, the code run but it didnt change anything in my mongodb

Comment: can you provide one document(data) in json format so that I will know the data format.

Comment: Is this the JSON format you need ? 

`Name: "xxx",
Age: 10,
Class: "ABC", 
Course: [ {Chemistry:100,Math:90}

into

Name: "xxx",
Age: 10,
Class: "ABC", 
Course: [ 
{Chemistry:100,Math:90,History: 80}`